# Sample size study not reflecting findings in R simulation

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, ab-test

I have a binomial response variable (a sort of conversion rate for a search mechanism) and just one independent variable, which is the "type" of the search bar template. To illustrate, my data would look somewhere near this:

| Response | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 0 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 0 | A |

One important detail is: the conversion baseline is now sitting at around 0.0024%. I was trying to use G*Power to see different required sample sizes if my new groups were to improve the conversion to different levels, from 0.003%, to 0.004%, and so on.

The issue is that G*Power, with its Chi-Squared Goodness-of-fit (Contingency Tables) option, keeps returning sample sizes that don't make sense to me. I simulated some data using R:

```
df_a = as.data.frame(rbinom(25000, 1, 0.0024))
df_a['group'] = 'group a'
colnames(df_a)[1] <- "success" 

df_b = as.data.frame(rbinom(25000, 1, 0.0024))
df_b['group'] = 'group b'
colnames(df_b)[1] <- "success" 
 
df_c = as.data.frame(rbinom(25000, 1, 0.003))
df_c['group'] = 'group c'
colnames(df_c)[1] <- "success" 

# merging
df = rbind(df_a, df_b, df_c)
tapply(df$sucesso, df$grupo, summary)

df %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  summarise(sucessos = sum(sucesso))
```

I've been playing around with different sample sizes for the groups, after locking the conversion rates to (0.0024% / 0.0024% / **0.003%**), since I would like to know how demanding the software would tell that my test needs to be.

By feeding the results of `table(df)`:

| Success Count | Group A | Group B | Group C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24951 | 24940 | 24923 |
| 1 | 49 | 60 | 77 |

So, after using a total sample size of 75.000 observations, I'm usually getting borderline significant p-values (around 0.04) when fitting the data via:

```
lr.model = glm(success~group,family="binomial", data=df)
lr.anova= anova(lr.model, test="Chisq")
lr.anova #ANOVA output
```

My intuition tells me that the correct sample size requirement pre-testing to detect such differences would be around the 15-25k observations, at least.

But this is what G*Power returns:

[image]

What am I missing here? Also, does the contingency table testing not take into account the 0.0025% proportion? The way I fill that board seems to ignore that.

Comment: just wanted to mention that anytime you are sampling anything in R, you should issue a set.seed at the start to be able to replicate the results. that is what may be happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the power analysis is for a completely different test, with null hypothesis that the three conditions A, B, C have equal probabilities and alternative that they don't.  The success probability isn't relevant for that test, which is why it's not used.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I see. Would you say the hypothesis I was going for with GPower is what a "regular abc test" would settle for studying? The difference in sample size required is indeed astronomical!

Comment: *edit: I'm realizing the 448 only seems smaller, but it is actually a count of the total of successes,  so my sample size will likewise be huge either way...